# is Windows Subsystem for Linux sufficient for BUILDING tasks using bitbake, gcc, cmake etc?

Tags: gcc, build, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bitbake

My project is currently using **VirtualBox + Ubuntu 18** running on **Windows (x86_64)** to build an `ARM` image using `bitbake`, `gcc`, `cmake`, `make`.

**QUESTION**

Is WSL sufficient for *building* activities that are currently running on virtual machine + Ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your builds do. If they try to do long double arithmetic, they will likely fail or be incorrect, due to this WSL bug:

- [long double floating point calculations give inexact results](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/830)

People have also reported issues with build tools caused by antivirus software on the host. Other imperfections in the Linux emulation may not matter if you are cross-compiling.

What likely matters is that WSL is so extremely slow when compared to virtualization, especially for file system operations. If your builds are split across many small files, switching to WSL from virtualization will likely result in a huge slowdown.

**EDIT** The above applies to the original WSL (`LXCORE.SYS`). WSL2 is based on Hyper-V and likely behaves much better (but I haven't tried it yet). The Hyper-V dependency however means that you have to disable Virtualbox completely.

Comment: That’s disappointing. What’s its use if it has two critical issues?

Comment: What do you mean **disable Virtualbox completely**?

Comment: As far as I know, Hyper-V is incompatible with the Virtualbox drivers. You have to choose one. (But I have not used Virtuablox personally in ages.)